# Api complains no-referrer-when-downgrade with Keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak

I am trying to secure my api service that is running on jetty with Keycloak according to the documentation on https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_jetty9_adapter.

I have created a **clients user-svc** that has the following installation in Keycloak:

```
{
  "realm": "databaker",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "user-svc",
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

The `jetty-web.xml` configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Get name="securityHandler">
        <Set name="authenticator">
            <New class="org.keycloak.adapters.jetty.KeycloakJettyAuthenticator">
                <Set name="adapterConfig">
                    <New class="org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig">
                        <Set name="realm">databaker</Set>
                        <Set name="resource">user-svc</Set>
                        <Set name="authServerUrl">http://localhost:8080/auth/</Set>
                        <Set name="sslRequired">external</Set>
                        <Set name="bearerOnly">true</Set>
                        <Set name="confidentialPort">0</Set>
                    </New>
                </Set>
            </New>
        </Set>
    </Get>
</Configure>
```

and `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>user-svc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.databaker.UserSvcServlet</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>user-svc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>user-svc</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>this is ignored currently</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:3000</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,PUT,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,Cache-Control</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>chainPreflight</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/genders</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/interests</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The `user-svc` service is running on `http://localhost:9090`

```
java -jar start.jar -Djetty.http.port=9090
2020-07-13 10:20:16 INFO  log:169 - Logging initialized @230ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2020-07-13 10:20:17 WARN  HomeBaseWarning:72 - This instance of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not recommended.  See documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
2020-07-13 10:20:17 INFO  Server:360 - jetty-9.4.29.v20200521; built: 2020-05-21T17:20:40.598Z; git: 77c232aed8a45c818fd27232278d9f95a021095e; jvm 11.0.7+10-LTS
2020-07-13 10:20:17 INFO  ScanningAppProvider:128 - Deployment monitor [file:///home/developer/playground/user-svc-env/jetty-svc/webapps/] at interval 1
2020-07-13 10:20:18 INFO  AnnotationConfiguration:473 - Scanning elapsed time=588ms
2020-07-13 10:20:18 INFO  session:334 - DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-07-13 10:20:18 INFO  session:339 - No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-07-13 10:20:18 INFO  session:140 - node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2020-07-13 10:20:18 INFO  ContextHandler:849 - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@14dd7b39{root,/,file:///tmp/jetty-0_0_0_0-9090-root_war-_-any-934191447021540237.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/home/developer/playground/user-svc-env/jetty-svc/webapps/root.war}
2020-07-13 10:20:18 INFO  AbstractConnector:331 - Started ServerConnector@18ca3c62{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:9090}
2020-07-13 10:20:18 INFO  Server:400 - Started @1892ms
```

When calling the api service from the webapp, I have got the following error message
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you aware you're specifying `localhost:8080` in the `jetty-web.xml` and using `http://localhost:9090` when running the service? try `java -jar start.jar -Djetty.http.port=8080`

Comment: Keycloak is running on `localhost:8080` address, that is the reason why I have specified on `jetty-web.xml`. The api service is running on `http://localhost:9090`. Your suggestion shows me: `Address already in use`.

Comment: I believe there is a proxy in the chain, isn't it? Can you please confirm (or not)? and eventually provide the full sequence of requests and subsequent responses (as curl script and output if possible). It could also be interesting to check the behavior if you set your client to ssl-required=none as well as in the adapter config (+ remove the line confidential-port: 0).